# How to bootstrap using large datasets?

Tags: r, memory, statistics-bootstrap

I would like to use the `boot()` and `boot.ci()` functions from `library("boot")` for a large data set(~20 000) with `type="bca"`.

If `R`(number of bootstraps) is too small (I have tried 1k - 10k), then I get the following error:

> Error in bca.ci(boot.out, conf, index[1L], L = L, t = t.o, t0 = t0.o,  :
>     estimated adjustment 'a' is NA

However, if I do 15k - 20+k bootstraps, then I get:

> Cannot allocate vector size # GB

(usually ranging from 1.7 to 6.4gb, depending on the dataset and # of bootstraps).

I read that I needed to have more ram, but I have Windows desktop with 16gb ram and I'm using 64-bit R, suggesting my computer should be able to handle this.

How can I use bootstrapping methods on larger datasets if too few bootstraps cannot produce estimates and sufficient bootstraps results in insufficient memory?

My code:

```
multRegress<-function(mydata){
          numVar<<-NCOL(mydata)
          Variables<<- names(mydata)[2:numVar]

          mydata<-cor(mydata, use="pairwise.complete.obs")
          RXX<-mydata[2:numVar,2:numVar]
          RXY<-mydata[2:numVar,1]

          RXX.eigen<-eigen(RXX)
          D<-diag(RXX.eigen$val)
          delta<-sqrt(D)

          lambda<-RXX.eigen$vec%*%delta%*%t(RXX.eigen$vec)
          lambdasq<-lambda^2
          beta<-solve(lambda)%*%RXY
          rsquare<<-sum(beta^2)

          RawWgt<-lambdasq%*%beta^2
          import<-(RawWgt/rsquare)*100

          result<<-data.frame(Variables, Raw.RelWeight=RawWgt, 
          Rescaled.RelWeight=import)
     }

# function passed to boot
multBootstrap <- function(mydata, indices){         
                   mydata<-mydata[indices,] 
                   multWeights<-multRegress(mydata) 
                   return(multWeights$Raw.RelWeight) 
                   }

# call boot
multBoot<-boot(thedata, multBootstrap, 15000)
multci<-boot.ci(multBoot,conf=0.95, type="bca")
```

Comment: how many statistics are you bootstrapping?

Comment: ...from https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/37918/why-is-the-error-estimated-adjustment-a-is-na-generated-from-r-boot-package#comment333957_37931 seems you need the number of reps to be at least the number of rows of your data

Comment: When I add the number of reps to be greater than or equal to the number of rows, I run out of memory, even at 1.7gb (even though I have 16gb memory on my cpu)

Comment: That is why I was asking how many parameters you are bootstrapping?

Comment: ... If you run a simple example of `bs <- boot(...)` and inspect the object you can see that it stores several objects. I'd expect the largest to be the data (`bs$data`) and the simulated statistics (`bs$t`) which will have dimension`R` (nsim) by n_parameters. If you have many many parameters this could be large. Otherwise it could be how you are generating the bootstrap
statistics -- your function -- that is causing the memory issues. Can you share the function that you are using in the `boot` call -- even better if you can supply a **small** reproducible example, data included.

Comment: I have 16 bootstrap statistics as I have 16 predictors in a relative weights analysis:

Comment: Thanks. Okay so from that description it seems unlikely that it is the data that is retuned by the boot function that is causing the memory issues. Are you parallelising the boot function - perhaps you dont have enough memory for it too be run on each core. Have you tracked the memory from one run of your model? Do you have any other large objects in your workspace that could be consuming memory - one way this could hapen is if you have loaded a pevious workspace; so try restarting r and run `ls()` straight away to see if there are any objects.

Comment: Thank you! How do I parallelise the boot function? I've done the restarting thing so it isn't my workspace.

Comment: it is documented in the `?boot` help page -- but this will not help your memory issue and will likely make it worse. So it could be the function that you are using -- try profiling the memory of it outside of boot https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7856306/monitor-memory-usage-in-r. I can't really offer anything else without seeing your model/data.

Comment: I have posted it. Sorry this is my first time asking a question here. I was having trouble showing you the code

Comment: Thanks. You seem to have posted helper functions for your results but not the function that you pass to `boot` i.e. `statistic=multBootstrap`

Comment: Does this help? lol sorry, thank you so much for your patience. multBootstrap<-function(mydata, indices){
 mydata<-mydata[indices,]
 multWeights<-multRegress(mydata)
 return(multWeights$Raw.RelWeight)
}

Comment: Thanks. I have updated your question (and removed functions that were not used in the code example). What package is `multRegress` from please?

Comment: Thank you so much! I have included the code for multRegress.

Comment: ... another link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5184953/memory-profiling-in-r-tools-for-summarizing

Comment: Thank you! I will look at that link. But shouldn't my desktop be able to handle "vector sizes of 1.7gb"?  I am running 64 bit R and I have 16 GB ram.

Comment: Sorry it seems as if i misunderstood;  can i check please; is it `boot.ci` that gives the memory issue rather than the `boot` function? (from some quick tests in seems as if bca is quite ram hungry)

Comment: It seems as if the `empinf` function (which is called from `boot:::bca.ci`) is slow. It is coded in base R had has several split-apply-combine routines. I think this could be made more memory efficient / fast by recoding it in data.table syntax but that seems a bit if a pain. There may be a way to get an estimate of the quantity that empinf returns (i dont know) but the folks at https://stats.stackexchange.com/ may have a suggestion.